# How can I center image in custom cell

Tags: iphone, ios

In my custom cell I want to center an image but this does not work.

```
    self.leftImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cry] autorelease] ;
    float h=cell.frame.size.height;
    float w=cell.frame.size.width;

    CGRect r = leftImage.frame;
    r.origin = cell.frame.origin;
    r.origin.x = w/ 2  - r.size.width / 2;
    r.origin.y = h / 2  - r.size.height / 2 + 12;
    leftImage.frame = r;
            [self.contentView addSubview:leftImage];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You tried to do this in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewRef cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` when creating new cell or in cell itself in init section. At this moments cell don't have correct *frame* and you can't rely on it.

Comment: i did it in (id)initWithCellIdentifier:(NSString *)cellID

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `leftImage`'s `autoresizingMask`:

```
self.leftImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin
```

When the cell is created, you're never sure what its dimensions are. Mostly, a cell will be initialized with a `CGRectZero` frame and later on, the `UITableView` will resize the cell appropriately.